# Converting C# to VB.net code to use an API

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hello I am using the ClickSend API to send SMS messages on my C# apps. I have to transfer this to a VB.Net app and ClickSend do not have an API or documentation on VB.Net.

Is there any tip or tricks to transfer this to VB.Net (ps I have tried online converters to no avail.)

API Code to Send SMS as seen below:

```
using IO.ClickSend.ClickSend.Api;
using IO.ClickSend.Client;
using IO.ClickSend.ClickSend.Model;

var configuration = new Configuration()
{
    Username = USERNAME, 
    Password = API_KEY  
};
var smsApi = new SMSApi(configuration);

var listOfSms = new List<SmsMessage>
{
    new SmsMessage(
        to: "+61411111111", 
        body: "test message", 
        source: "sdk"
    )
};

var smsCollection = new SmsMessageCollection(listOfSms);
var response = smsApi.SmsSendPost(smsCollection);
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need to rewrite it in VB? If it’s in your contract then fire the client. Microsoft effectively killed VB with the latest .NET 5 news.

Comment: What issues have you had with using an online converter?

Comment: It has to be VB.net as the clients entire repertoire is in vb.net. Can you help?

Comment: Why can't you just write the VB.NET code yourself? Exactly what part of that code do you not understand?

Comment: For future reference, I strongly recommend installing [Instant VB](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp-to-vb-converter.html) as it is far superior to any online converter.

Answer (score 2):

What problem did you have with the online converters?

Here's the output from https://converter.telerik.com

```
Dim configuration = New Configuration() With {
    .Username = USERNAME,
    .Password = API_KEY
}
Dim smsApi = New SMSApi(configuration)
Dim listOfSms = New List(Of SmsMessage) From {
    New SmsMessage([to]:="+61411111111", body:="test message", source:="sdk")
}
Dim smsCollection = New SmsMessageCollection(listOfSms)
Dim response = smsApi.SmsSendPost(smsCollection)
```

It seems pretty good to me.

Comment: I think that there is problem with those using ... lines. Converter is not able to convert the code as it is. However when separated as in this answer the conversion works.